# DBeaver does not recognize declared variable when executing SQL script on SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2016, dbeaver

We are using DBeaver Community Edition (v23.2.0.202309041200) as a client connecting to Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.5101.9).

The issue happens when executing the below SQL statements in DBeaver as a script.

```sql
declare @option as int = 2;

select @option;
```

The action "Execute SQL script", or by DBeaver hot key `Alt+X`, always fails on the selecting statement, with error message saying `SQL Error [137] [S0002]: Must declare the scalar variable "@option".`.

The error does not happen if we highlight the two SQL statements and go with action "Execute SQL query", or by DBeaver hot key `Ctrl+Enter`.

The error does not happen either if we use Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, so we do not believe the issue is related to SQL Server.

**Our Question:**

Is there any way we can use declared variables in DBeaver when executing a SQL script on MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server)?

We highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

Comment: I find DBeaver's docs slightly ambiguous on this. If you remove the semicolon `;` from the first line, such that it's written as `declare @option as int = 2`, does the script work with `ALT + X`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is DBeaver's issue as it has its own way of processing sql scripts compared to SSMS or Azure data studio.

In DBeaver, each SQL statement in a script is executed separately and therefore, any variable declared in one statement is not available in following statements.

Workaround : use `@set` which is a DBeaver command.

```
@set option = 2
select :option
```

Note: Please note that this approach may not work if you intend to run your scripts outside of DBeaver, because `@set` and `:variable_name` are specific to DBeaver and may not be recognized by other SQL clients or SQL Server itself.

ref: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2244#issuecomment-333441954 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/67193585/1387418

Comment: "*In DBeaver, each SQL statement in a script is executed separately*" - I don't believe this to be true, based on their (somewhat ambiguous) [documentation on the shortcuts](https://dbeaver.com/docs/dbeaver/Shortcuts/#cur_query) which has a separate shortcut for "*Execute SQL script*" which is `ALT+X` from the shortcut for "*Execute SQL statement*" which is `CTRL+ENTER`. The docs sound like what OP wants to accomplish should work in the manner that they're trying.

Answer (score 0):

Use BEGIN and END. It work for me. Example:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE @name VARCHAR(10);
  SET @name = 'My Name';
  SELECT @name AS NAME;
END;
```

For your case:

```
BEGIN
  declare @option as int = 2;
  select @option;
END;
```

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77566399 for some additional details.